# Arc shape coming out strangely

Tags: python, tkinter, shapes

I am trying to make a catch the egg game and it is going fine apart from the basket, which is supposed to look like an arc upside-down but it became a very strange shape, and I have searched as far as I could but no one has had such a problem like this.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I'll have to post the whole program otherwise you wouldn't understand:

```py
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, messagebox, font

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(
    root,
    width=canvas_width,
    height=canvas_height,
    background="deep sky blue"
)
c.create_rectangle(
    -5,
    canvas_height - 100,
    canvas_width + 5,
    canvas_height + 5,
    fill="sea green",
    width=0
)
c.create_oval(-80, -80, 120, 120, fill="orange", width=0)
c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle([
    "light blue",
    "light green",
    "light pink",
    "light yellow",
    "light cyan"
])

egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000

difficulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color = "blue"
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_width - 20
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x = catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height
catcher = c.create_arc(
    catcher_start_x,
    catcher_start_y,
    catcher_start_x2,
    catcher_start_y2,
    start=200,
    extent=140,
    style="arc",
    outline=catcher_color,
    width=30
)

game_font = font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
game_font.config(size=18)
score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(
    10,
    10,
    anchor="nw" ,
    font=game_font,
    fill="darkblue",
    text="Score: " + str(score)
)

lives_remaining = 3
lives_text = c.create_text(
    canvas_width - 10,
    10,
    anchor="ne",
    font=game_font,
    fill="darkblue",
    text="Lives " + str(lives_remaining)
)

eggs = []


def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 740)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(
        x,
        y,
        x + egg_width,
        y + egg_height,
        fill=next(color_cycle),
        width=0
    )
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)


def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)


def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!", "Final Score: " + str(score))
        root.destroy()


def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text = "Lives: " + str(lives_remaining))


def check_catch():
    catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2 = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2 = c.coords(egg)
        if egg_x<catcher_x<egg_x2 and (catcher_y2 - egg_y2) < 5:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(100, check_catch)
    

def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * difficulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * difficulty_factor)
    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text="Score: " + str(score))


def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)


def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)


c.bind("<Left>" , move_left)
c.bind("<Right>", move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you update the question and post a picture of what you expect the basket looks like?

Comment: Let me see if i can find a picture online or something

Comment: There we go I am trying to make it look something like this @accdias

Comment: Alright. I'll see if I can find what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on line 27 - you have written `catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x = catcher_width` where you should have `catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x - catcher_width`.

Also, the backslash on line 29 is unnecessary as things contained in brackets automatically continue on multiple lines.

One more thing - once the typo is fixed, the eggs are only caught in the left area of the catcher because line 79 (`if egg_x<catcher_x<egg_x2 and (catcher_y2 - egg_y2) < 5:`) is checking if the left x coord of the catcher is inside the x coords of the egg not the other way around. To fix this, replace it with
`if catcher_x - 10 < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 + 10 and (catcher_y2 - egg_y2) < 5:` (the -10 and +10 are to give the player a bit of leeway so the egg doesn't have to be exactly in the centre).